# a better JQuery Toggle Switch?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am trying to create a simple toggle **+EXPAND/-COLLAPSE** toggle switch.

At start:

The HTML:

```
<div class="ttoggle">
  <div class="expand">+ EXPAND</div>
  <div class="collapse hide">- COLLAPSE</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hide { display:none;}
```

JQuery:

```
    var x="collapse";
 $('.ttoggle').click(function() {
    if(x=="collapse") {
     $(this).find('.'+x).removeClass("hide");
     $(this).find('.expand').addClass("hide");
        x="expand";

    } else if(x=="expand") {
        $(this).find('.'+x).removeClass("hide");
        $(this).find('.collapse').addClass("hide");
        x="collapse";
    }

});
```

This, I think is a terrible way to write a toggle code, looks heavy with the use of a variable to register states...there ought to be a better/lighter way to make this work....any hints?? Thanks!

Comment: Are you just toggling one item? Or is it a bunch of things like a collapsible menu?

Comment: Why not just replace the inner HTML when you click the switch? Or are the divs styled differently? (colors etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want clicking ttoggle to display +EXPAND at first, then when clicked it should display -COLLAPSE. Clicking again would again display +EXPAND.

Could something like this work?

```
$('.ttoggle').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.expand, .collapse').toggleClass('hide');
}
```

Comment: yes! Works like a charm...this is exactly what i wanted a - lighter code! Perfect. Thanks Bemmu!

Comment: if the code answers your question and meets your needs, I recommend selecting it as the answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at some library code for inspiration here. Lots of the UI libraries have a toggle component. Where the value is best stored depends on the rest of your front end. For example, if you're using a Backbone framework, perhaps the Backbone.View should store the toggle state. Or, if you're going to submit this in the form, store the toggle state in a hidden input. Bootstrap's buttons are well thought out, and they have a toggle one: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups

For a one-off case, I suggest a data attribute or hidden input, as in:

HTML

```
<div id="MyToggle" data-isCollapsed="true">Expand</div>
```

JS

```
$('#MyToggle').click(function(){
  $(this).data('isCollapsed') = ! $(this).data('isCollapsed')
})
```